# Getting earliest time based on bean property value

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashmap

I am using Spring Boot application and trying to get earliest `timeStart` based on `tag` of Schedule POJO class.

I have a simple bean with getter and setter methods -

Schedule.java

```
public class Schedule {
  private String id;
  private String tag;
  private String timeStart;
}
```

When I do a for loop of this class list as follows:-

```
List<Schedule> schedules = someAPI();
for (Schedule schedule : schedules) {
   LOGGER.info("schedule : "+schedule );
}
```

Then I get the following output:-

```
schedule: [ID = 561, Tag = A1, timeStart = 2019-07-26 15:33:00]
schedule: [ID = 562, Tag = A1, timeStart = 2019-07-24 11:33:00]
schedule: [ID = 563, Tag = A1, timeStart = 2019-07-25 12:33:00]
schedule: [ID = 564, Tag = A2, timeStart = 2019-07-26 14:33:00]
schedule: [ID = 565, Tag = A2, timeStart = 2019-07-26 15:33:00]
```

Now I want to get the smallest `timeStart` by `tag name` and store in DB, so I need the output something like the following;-

```
A1 -> 2019-07-24 11:33:00
A2 -> 2019-07-26 14:33:00
```

I tried the following (to put the timeStarts by tag name in a hashmap)-

```
Map < String, ArrayList < String >> timeStartsByTag = new HashMap < String, ArrayList < String >> ();
ArrayList < String > timeStarts = new ArrayList < String > ();
for (Schedule schedule: schedules) {
    if (timeStarts.isEmpty()) {
        timeStarts.add(schedule.getTimeStart());
    }
    if (!timeStarts.isEmpty() && timeStartsByTag.containsKey(schedule.getTag())) {
        timeStarts.add(schedule.getTimeStart());
    }
    timeStartsByTag.put(schedule.getTag(), timeStarts);
}
```

It is not working.

Comment: Please check my solution also, I have considered the `timeStarts` as an actual timestamp not as a string.  Please let me know of it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code your don't compare the `timeStart` value.  So it cannot work.

Besides all that may be simplified with the `Collectors.toMap()` overload that expects the merge function :

```
List<Schedule> schedules = someAPI();
Map<String, String> map = 
schedules.stream()
         .collect(toMap(Schedule::getTag, Schedule::getTimeStart, 
                        (t1,t2)-> t1.compareTo(t2) < 0 ? t1 : t2))
                );
```

Here `String.compareTo()` works because a lexicographical order matches to your **current** requirement but that is brittle. Using `LocalDateTime` or `Instant` to represent   `2019-07-24 11:33:00` makes more sense.

Comment: that is working great with this shortcode. So, if I also need to get Schedule::getTimeEnd for those same tags then I need to use another map? Or it can be combined in the same map?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could write a more sophisticated merge operation that returns as value a couple of value : min timeStart and min timeEnd for the current key.

Comment: merging multiple values into one is good but seems it needs advanced knowledge of java 8 collections. :)  Anyways, nice. The 2 separate maps are also good unless there is any performance overhead.

Comment: My God, agreed. No value to make things more complex without requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the `String` timestamps to `LocalDateTime` parsed using a `DateTimeFormatter` and compare them after grouping the `List<Schedule>` by tag name.

Using a downstream collector `Collectors.collectingAndThen()` it would get me the lowest timestamp by using a `Collectors.minBy(Comparator<LocalDateTime>)` and the corresponding `timeStart` field from the `Optional<Schedule>` returned by it:

```
 List<Schedule> schedules = new ArrayList<>();
 schedules.add(new Schedule( "561", "A1", "2019-07-26 15:33:00"));
 schedules.add(new Schedule( "562", "A1", "2019-07-24 11:33:00"));
 schedules.add(new Schedule( "563", "A1", "2019-07-25 12:33:00"));
 schedules.add(new Schedule( "564", "A2", "2019-07-26 14:33:00"));
 schedules.add(new Schedule( "565", "A2", "2019-07-26 15:33:00"));

 DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 Map<String, String> map = schedules.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Schedule::getTag,
                     Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.minBy(
                     Comparator.comparing(sch -> LocalDateTime.parse(sch.getTimeStart() ,dtf))), 
                     optional -> optional.get().getTimeStart())));
 System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

`{A1=2019-07-24 11:33:00, A2=2019-07-26 14:33:00}`